# Signal of mobile network

Tags: gsm

Hi i want to have a circuit design for amplifying the mobile phone signal as at my place where i live the signal is very weak. or show me a site where it can help me please.

Comment: You do realize that mobile phone signals are bi-directional - if your receive signal is weak then it's likely that your transmit signal is also weak - this complicates things enormously. Also, have you considered that the receive circuit in your mobile is nearly always going to be better than anything you might be able to make or find a design for on the web.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few factors in GSM amplicfication. Not just a simple circuit but also what kind of antennas you use.

This is a £190 900mhz (EU) one way repeater system that uses a good quality high gain antenna and gives you and output of 60db that can cover 250 square metres.
[image]

You can find cheaper ones even at £40 - but beware as they use cheap components and low quality antennas with extraordinary claims. But you can always take it apart and see for your self how it is done.

Then you get the bidirectional 2100mhz / 3G/ UMTS that cost more. BUt they are designed to increase the coverage both ways. So if you have 0 signal in your basement you can use one of these and you will get normal coverage (ref CAE50-2100 Single BAND UMTS/3G REPEATER - You then get a massive breakdown in repeaters, dualband 900/1800, single band, 3G only, carrier specific.. )

[image]

And then you get the mother of all of them.. (ref- Nextivity) The cover everything, voice and data - But are only carrier specific...(o2, vodafone, etc..)

[image]

Actually trying to find a circuit diagram is like finding a needle in a haystack. These circuits require a processor and finely tuned components to work properly.

Comment: Will this work for mobile phones in two-way conversation?

Comment: They do generally work, yes. If you can get on the network at all you should be able to make a two-way call by the nature of how GSM works.

Comment: That model only rebroadcasts the tower. I updated to show ones that are bidirectional.